# Amazon AWS and Tomcat war file deployment

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, war

if i have already developed servlet for the `Tomcat` server, can I use it **as is** and deploy using the `AWS Elastic Beanstalk`? Has anybody experience with that?

Thanks,
STeN

Comment: I read the title and figured that AWS and Tomcat are fighting a war!! Reminds me of Tom and Jerry. :)

Comment: Funny, I read it now again and have the same feeling:)))